# Laravel Blade double brackets and templates not working but php echo does

Tags: php

This works fine using php echo

```
    <!-- app/views/example.blade.php -->

    <p><?php echo $taylorTheVampireSlayer; ?></p>
```

The below code out puts the double brackets.

Seems like the blade templating system isn' working on my localhost/lampstack.

I have checked all permissions and tried the original code to

```
   <!-- app/views/example.blade.php -->


   <p>{{ $taylorTheVampireSlayer }}</p>
```

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is make sure there is no white space saved in your file name. It must end in `.blade.php`. Try a `composer dump-autoload` (doubt it's the issue but its been known to solve odd problems).

Answer (score 3):

Try using these!

```
Blade::setContentTags('{{', '}}');      // for variables and all things Blade    
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');     // for escaped data
```

Hope this helps! happy larveling :)

Comment: Thanks guys still no luck, I just don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it has been solved by changing the name of the views by adding " .blade " between "name" and ".php" like Eluong said.

name.php : issues
name.blade.php : solved